# How to get instant windows toast notifications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, notification-area

I am talking about the new notification center:

[image: Notificationcenter]

Sometimes I receive a toast notification for an email, I have read and answered hours ago. When opening the notification center, I see many emails, I already have seen, but didn't got a toast notification.

[image: Notifications]

I think the problem has started about a half year ago. If I recall correct, Cortana said something along the lines "*While you were busy, I kept some notifications away from you.*"

How can I configure windows, to show me a new notification (for example Mail) at the moment I receive it? A year ago, this was the standard setting.

I don't find anything usefull in *System -> Notifications and Actions*. Everything is enabled.

Comment: Are you utilizing the built-in Windows 10 **Mail** app?  If so, you probably need to adjust the synchronization settings:  [How To Change Email Sync Frequency in the Windows 10 Mail App](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-server/how-change-email-sync-frequency-windows-10-mail-app)

Comment: No, I am using Outlook 2016. In Outlook I see my new Mails nearly instant (already synchronized), but don't get the notification for it. @Run5k Also in the "Message Arrival" Section, I have enabled "show Desktop notifications". Not sure if it is an outlook only problem.

Comment: There have been reports that disabling Cortana helps with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that "Show notification banners" option is enabled for Outlook in Notifications & actions for your Windows 10:

[image]

Besides, if you have inbox rules to move emails to subfolder, ensure that you have the "Display a Desktop Alert" action ticked. Otherwise, no notification will display for these incoming emails moved by a rule.

[image]